# Slave nodes not starting or adding to my apache spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, redhat

"I am setting up a new apache-spark 2 node cluster"
Problem: Slave node is not getting started.

1. First I haven't edited my /etc/hosts file because I want to install & start manually on my machine.
2. In conf/slaves I have provided the single slave host name in master node and as well as in the slave node directory
3. I have configured different SPARK_HOME paths in .bashrc. in master node host, we have given  the master node directory path while in slave node host we had given the slave node directory path.
4. After inclusion of all details in every host .bashrc file. I have tried to start the cluster. master node getting start but not slave node. I am getting the below error.

master node starts in right process but while after ssh into slave host it pops this below error

```
slave-host-0001: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /apps/abc5/xyz-folder/spark/master/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-xxxx-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-slave-host-0001.out
slave-host-0001: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /apps/abc5/xyz-folder/spark/master/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://master-host-0001:7077
slave-host-0001:   JAVA_HOME is not set
slave-host-0001: full log in /apps/abc5/xyz-folder/spark/master/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-xxxx-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-slave-host-0001.out
```

It says JAVA_HOME is not set but other applications working right way using same JAVA_HOME path

.bash configurations:

```
JAVA_HOME=/apps/abc1/jdk1.8.0_45
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME

PYTHON_HOME=/apps/abc1/python/python-3.6.4
export PYTHON_HOME=/apps/abc1/python/python-3.6.4

SCALA_HOME=/apps/abc5/xyz-folder/scala-2.13.0
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME

SPARK_HOME=/apps/abc5/xyz-folder/spark/inpera-slave-01/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:$PYTHON_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin:/users/clip/.local/bin:/users/clip/bin:/apps/abc1/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/apps/abc5/xyz-folder/scala-2.13.0/bin:/apps/abc5/xyz-folder/spark/inpera-slave-01/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
```

Questions:
1. why it is directing to the master node path though it is successfully logging into slave host. As expected, we need to go slave node directory right? 

2. Why we were getting the JAVA_HOME error in the slave node host?

Thank you all in advance for your valuable responses.

Answer (score 0):

[problem solved]
I have been using .bash_profile for all the paths (JAVA, PYTHON, SCALA, SPARK).

Spark is looking for .bashrc by default.

Set up JAVA_HOME path in .bashrc.

Problem solved....

Comment: I have same problem even though JAVA_HOME is set in .bashrc